# PHP adLDAP not working

Tags: php

I am trying authenticate users to my application through Active Directory using `adLDAP.php` but it is not authenticating users and also returns `Notice: Undefined property: adLDAP::$user in C:\wamp\www\example\index.php on line 21`.

```
require_once('/adLDAP/src/adLDAP.php');
try {
    $adldap = new adLDAP();
}
catch (adLDAPException $e) {
    echo $e;
    exit();   
}

if ( isset($_POST['logonUser'])){
   $staff_id = $_POST['staff_id'];
   $password = $_POST['password'];

   $authUser = $adldap->user()->authenticate($staff_id, $password);

   if ($authUser == true) {
      echo '<h1> Login successful </h1>';
   }
   else {
      echo "<h1> $adldap->user()->getLastError() </h1>";
      echo "<h1> Login unsuccessful. Try again! </h1>";
   }
}
```

Any help will be deeply appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure your `adLDAP` class has public function `user()`? I am guessing it should be `$adldap->authenticate($staff_id, $password);`

Comment: Javad is correct. you also need to make sure you have an appropriate bind dn configured.

Comment: @Javad: I have tried that too. It didn't work.

Comment: @Yax As Brad said, did bind default DN in your adLDAP config? After trying changes what error comes up?

Comment: @Javad: all my configurations are okay. And the class, `user` and `getLastError` exist in the **adLDAP.php**.

Comment: @Yax Was it the same error an same line after changes?

Comment: @Javad: I don't understand how I can `bind default DN in your adLDAP config`.

Comment: @Javad: `$this->ldapBind = @ldap_bind($this->ldapConnection, $username . $this->accountSuffix, $password);`

Comment: @Yax You have two options: 1) Directly in adLDAP class set the proper values for `protected $_base_dn = "O=MyDomain";` and `protected $_domain_controllers = array ('www.mydomain.com');` and if the port is different you can change that one, too otherwise as default it's set as *389*;  2) when you create new instance of the adLDAP pass the proper config params like `$adldap = new adLDAP(array('base_dn' => 'myDomain', 'domain_controllers' => 'www.mydomain.com'));`

Comment: @Javad: Have done that, the first choice. It still says `Notice: Undefined property: adLDAP::$getLastError in C:\wamp\www\example\index.php on line 21`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52626/discussion-between-javad-and-yax)